# ESP32: How can I shorten wifi-connection time to AWS?

Tags: esp32, freertos

ESP32 is sending temperature and humidity data from sensors to AWS over wifi and it's working otherwise fine, but wifi-connection is "on" for about 20 seconds. I'd need to shorten the connection time to save battery.

Can it be done? How short I can get it, practically? Where can I find more info on how to do it?

Comment: I don't know the ESP32 HAL / software framework, but there's certainly a "turn off Wifi" function you can call after your transmission has been successful, right? Call that function.

Comment: How long does it take if you run the same code on a PC than on the ESP32?

Comment: Can you provide power to a base station nearby, and use a lower power protocol between sensor and base station (which then sends to AWS)?

Comment: It seems a difficult question to give you answers, because you didn't described the circuit and the code. _Can it be done?_ Yes. _How short I can get it, practically?_ A few seconds, but the real ansewer depends on what's in your code. _Where can I find more info on how to do it?_ Google.

Comment: Use a WiFi access point where you can run packet sniffing software (eg use a PC *as* an AP) and monitor the entire exchange to see how long it takes. Look for time gaps and understand them. Compare to ESP active time.

Comment: How long does it take the ESP32 to establish a connection to your wifi and disconnect immediately after this is successful. This would be your minimum connection time. Then per the other comments the rest of the time goes to the efficiency of communication with AWS. A few timestamps in the code might give you an idea if you can't run a packet sniffer.

Comment: Welcome to why wifi is not a great protocol for low power systems and IOT... But it is convenient...

Answer (score 0):

You can't shorten the connection time by much. Reconnecting to WiFi then reconnecting to AWS IoT Core takes a bit of time. You're authenticating to the WiFi base station, then connecting MQTT to AWS with certificate authentication and then (assuming you're using Shadows) the device is syncing the shadow. It takes time on a tiny device.

That said, you could potentially bring down the time by increasing WiFi power in menuconfig (assuming you're using IDF) but that probably would end up in a wash. It would spend slightly less time but spend more power. But you could try it and see what happens.

My recommendation which doesn't answer your exact question but more the idea of battery saving: You could amortize the cost of the power hungry WiFi if you don't need the sensors continually running. You can put the chip in sleep mode which turns off radio, CPU, and RAM. There a couple of [sleep modes](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html) (deep and light mode) in ESP32. With a properly designed power supply, the chip will only consume a few uA of quiescent current when sleeping which leaves more power for WiFi to later consume. Also note you'd need to take special care of saving state in RTC or NVS memory if needed. Coming out of sleep is *almost* like a reboot. If you don't want to do this what you could benefit from is ESP32's [Power Management API](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/power_management.html).